How to get better visualization of double brackets in mathematica workbench like we see in mathematica Notebook?
I am using Mathematica 14. And Recently to get the advantages of IDE I started using Mathematica Workbench which just uses Eclipse IDE.
One benifit of Notebook I am really missing is the double bracket visualization.
I seached fo add ons, but didn't see anything. May be using different fonts might help. Then which one?
